# Pyspark Corrupted ZIP library and RuntimeError: Java gateway process exited errors

Tags: java, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

These errors have come up a few times on here, however, none of the remedies seemed to work for me.

I need PySpark to run on my MacBook Pro M1. After I import `from pyspark.sql import SparkSession` followed by `spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()` I get hit with

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Corrupted ZIP library: /opt/anaconda3/lib/libzip.dylib
/Users/rcd/spark/bin/spark-class: line 97: CMD: bad array subscript
head: illegal line count -- -1.
```

Dozens of references follow this initial error message, each mentioning  `SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()`.

The final error message is as follows: `RuntimeError: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number.`

I've tried adding several lines to both my bash and zsh profiles, as recommended by users here. I've also tried updating my Java installation and adding other Java (JDK) updates. At one point I received a message saying a specific library was corrupt, so I went to conda and re-downloaded the library, but this had no effect.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this and get PySpark running?